# how does Windows implement clipboard format conversion?

Tags: winapi, clipboard, sandbox

i am implementing clipboard for my application sandbox system on Windows. I have to simulate clipboard behaviors by myself. Now all work fine except for format conversion part, i can do it for CF_TEXT/UNICODETEXT/OEMTEXT, but there are other formats that i am not familiar with like DIB. Is there any sample codes illustrating how Windows does this?

Comment: How Windows does *what*? BTW, there are tons of them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats

Comment: This is both too broad, and also a recommendation question, and therefore not suited to this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between `CF_DIB` and other clipboard formats is that it contains memory objects of `BITMAPINFO` structure and bitmap bits.

The [msdn document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#example-of-a-clipboard-viewer) has provided a very detailed example:

```
HINSTANCE hinst; 
UINT uFormat = (UINT)(-1); 
BOOL fAuto = TRUE; 
 
LRESULT APIENTRY MainWndProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam) 
HWND hwnd; 
UINT uMsg; 
WPARAM wParam; 
LPARAM lParam; 
{ 
    static HWND hwndNextViewer; 
 
    HDC hdc; 
    HDC hdcMem; 
    PAINTSTRUCT ps; 
    LPPAINTSTRUCT lpps; 
    RECT rc; 
    LPRECT lprc; 
    HGLOBAL hglb; 
    LPSTR lpstr; 
    HBITMAP hbm; 
    HENHMETAFILE hemf; 
    HWND hwndOwner; 
 
    switch (uMsg) 
    { 
        case WM_PAINT: 
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
 
            // Branch depending on the clipboard format. 
 
            switch (uFormat) 
            { 
                case CF_OWNERDISPLAY: 
                    ...
 
                case CF_BITMAP: 
                    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); 
                    if (hdcMem != NULL) 
                    { 
                        if (OpenClipboard(hwnd)) 
                        { 
                            hbm = (HBITMAP) 
                                GetClipboardData(uFormat); 
                            SelectObject(hdcMem, hbm); 
                            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc); 
 
                            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, 
                                hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); 
                            CloseClipboard(); 
                        } 
                        DeleteDC(hdcMem); 
                    } 
                    break; 
...
```

If you need to save the obtained bitmap object as a file, then you must strictly follow the [BITMAPINFOHEADER structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader) to assign values.

MSDN code sample: [Storing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/storing-an-image)